# Screen tearing and graphical glitches in Loki

Tags: release-loki, display, amd, video-player

I installed elementary OS Loki last night, and I have noticed that when I login the screen will do some weird glitch and then go to desktop. This also happens sometimes when I switch workplaces.

My other issue is with scrolling in Firefox and watching videos. 
Playing a movie from HDD using VLC the video playback is far from smooth. 
In Firefox while I'm scrolling I get a kind of "invisible line" that I can only describe as screen tearing distorting the text.

Sorry if I'm not explaining it well enough, but I'll be happy to answer any questions!

My system:

- AMD Athlon X4 860k
- 8GB DDR3
- Radeon 7850 2GB
- random assortment of HDDs

Answer (score 3):

To fix Firefox tearing, try opening about:config, setting `gfx.xrender.enabled` to `true`, then restart Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Please go to the gpu site and click downloads click graphics driver select ubuntu or linux option and ur 64 bit or 32bit archetecture option that will help you out otherwise delete firefox and try reinstalling or try google chrome still the prob persists post ur reply pleaseee we are ready to help you out .

Comment: You should precise what you mean by "GPU site".

Comment: I think @gauthamkrishnanp is probably using the term gpu (Graphical Processing Unit) when he should have used just "Graphic card" Probably the page he's pointing out is http://support.amd.com/en-us/download

Answer (score 0):

You definitely do not have proper video driver. I have [the same problem](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/8489/intel-graphics-performance-on-loki) on Intel (not Radeon) hardware.
I recommend to [install the drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/283345/how-to-install-drivers-for-amd-radeon-hd-7850#283360) as it is done on Ubuntu.