# Intel graphics performance on Loki

Tags: graphic-drivers, intel

I have bad video performance in Loki. After some googling I found this hint: [Cannot Install Intel Proprietary Graphics Driver](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7688/cannot-install-intel-proprietary-graphics-driver) and with some dirty trick (I put the Ubuntu 16.04 data in /etc/lsb-release file) installed the latest Intel video drivers.
Unfortunately after doing all this I see no change in performance.

Any hints?

Comment: I have seen this: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1734/how-do-i-install-the-latest-intel-linux-graphics and even commented that in Loki it won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Intel Graphics has some settings you can fine-tune to improve performance or powersavings.

Long story short, if you want the best performance create `/etc/modprobe.d/i915.conf` as **root** and add `options i915  powersave=0 enable_rc6=0 enable_fbc=0` to it.

If you want more settings or a further understanding of this options just write on a terminal `modinfo -p i915` .
Then, to add any extra setting just do it following the scheme of `setting=number` or `setting=true/false` (in case it's a boolean)

---

[Source](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/intel_graphics)

Comment: Thank you for answer. Unfortunately it doesn't work as proposed here. It seems that the reading of the intel manual us unavoidable...

Comment: What isn't working exactly? The settings don't work or some work but some don't??

Comment: I did a short test doing what you've written in this answer. There is no difference, the performance remains unacceptable. I did not dig the source at arch wiki so far. I _hope_ I will find there anything helpful.

Comment: How do you measure the performance? A game, a video, a test...?

Anyway installing the intel drivers from the intel site won't give you any extra performance in most cases. Except if you have a pretty new computer. What graphics do you have? use `lspci  | grep VGA ` to know it if you are not sure.

Comment: It is [Intel® HD Graphics 5500](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5327#sp). I did not make any measurement. It is really visible. On my Freya installation 1080i 60fps video is very smooth and I see that Freya delivers 60fps. On Loki these videos are much slower. I cannot say precisely how much, but I feel about 10 to 20 fps.

Comment: I've forgotten to mention, that it is visible just in GUI, All animations, drags and so on are not as snappy as on Freya. This annoys a lot.

Comment: [Here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7688/cannot-install-intel-proprietary-graphics-driver/8474#8474) I described how I installed the latest intel drivers.

Comment: Well, considering your CPU is from 2013 I'd say that installing the lastest intel drivers from their site is a bad idea. elementary OS has quite recent versions of everything related to graphics cards so I'm sure the problem doesn't come from that.   

I remember that in my laptop it was impossible to play 1080 60fps videos (from youtube using firefox) with an Intel Graphics HD 4000 but now it works just fine. I didn't update anything besides the updates that elementary pushes.  
If you have some time, the easiest solution would be installing elementary OS again.

Comment: And this time don't try to install those intel drivers. Your issue is really weird. Most likely caused by something you've installed.
I don't know what else you could do. Good luck with that.

Comment: I have reinstalled Loki from scratch. The problem disappeared.